# Switch statements with while loops

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement

```
do{ 
        cout << "Select an option from the Menu:  ";
        cin >> choice;
         // Validate the menu selection
            while ((choice < 1) || (choice > 3)){
                cout << "Incorrect input!, please enter an option from 1 to 3."<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter your choice: ";
                cin >> choice;
            }
        // Processing the users choice
            if (choice != 3){ 
        // Compute conversions
                switch (choice){
                        case 1:
                            cout<<""<<endl; 
                            cout<<"You have selected to convert Fijian Dollars to Vanuatuan Vatu."<<endl;
                            cout<<"Enter the amount you wish to convert: ";
                            cin >> amount;
                            conversion = amount * FJD_to_Vatu_Rate;
                        break;

                        case 2: 
                            cout<<""<<endl;
                            cout<<"You have selected to convert Fijian Dollars to Samoan Tala."<<endl;
                            cout<<"Enter the amount you wish to convert: ";
                            cin >> amount;
                            conversion = amount * FJD_to_Tala_Rate;
                        break;

                        case 3:
                            cout<<"Here the history will be shown"<<endl;
                            cout<<""<<endl;
                            cout<<"Do You want to perform another conversion? (Y/N) ";
                            cin >> repeat;
                                if (repeat == 'Y'){
                                    (This is what i want to know)
                                 }
                            cout<<"Thank you for using this program, goodbye!"<<endl;
                            return 0;

            }
        // Display the monthly charges
            cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
            cout << "The converted amount is: " << conversion << endl;
            cout <<""<<endl;
        }
    } while (choice != 3);
    cout<<"Thank you for using this program, goodbye!"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

The above is my part of my code for a currency converter, can anyone tell me if what to do in the section where it says "this is what i want to know" so that the program asks user to enter a choice so it can process it and use the choice to compute using one of the other cases.

Thanks

Comment: In your `switch`, case `3` will never happen, because of the `if` condition before the `switch`.

Comment: Hint: The whole thing is already in a do-while loop, so what can you do to either break the loop or let it continue?

Comment: Remove if condition from above because case 3 will never be executed.

Comment: This program is hardly minimal and it's not a compete program. SO questions want a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `if` statement before `switch` because `case 3:` will never be executed in this case.

```
do{ 
        cout << "Select an option from the Menu:  ";
        cin >> choice;
         // Validate the menu selection
            while ((choice < 1) || (choice > 3)){
                cout << "Incorrect input!, please enter an option from 1 to 3."<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter your choice: ";
                cin >> choice;
            }
        // Processing the users choice
        // Compute conversions
                switch (choice){
                        case 1:
                            cout<<""<<endl; 
                            cout<<"You have selected to convert Fijian Dollars to Vanuatuan Vatu."<<endl;
                            cout<<"Enter the amount you wish to convert: ";
                            cin >> amount;
                            conversion = amount * FJD_to_Vatu_Rate;
                        break;

                        case 2: 
                            cout<<""<<endl;
                            cout<<"You have selected to convert Fijian Dollars to Samoan Tala."<<endl;
                            cout<<"Enter the amount you wish to convert: ";
                            cin >> amount;
                            conversion = amount * FJD_to_Tala_Rate;
                        break;

                        case 3:
                            cout<<"Here the history will be shown"<<endl;
                            cout<<""<<endl;
                            cout<<"Do You want to perform another conversion? (Y/N) ";
                            cin >> repeat;
                                if (repeat == 'Y'){
                                    (This is what i want to know)
                                 }
                            cout<<"Thank you for using this program, goodbye!"<<endl;
                            return 0;

                        // Display the monthly charges
                        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
                        cout << "The converted amount is: " << conversion << endl;
                        cout <<""<<endl;    
                }
    } while (choice != 3);
    cout<<"Thank you for using this program, goodbye!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To restart do-while loop use `continue`. Logically you should print history first first, then do question\check.